# calculation of average number get way to high. I don't get why?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I am trying to get the average number of an array but the output is way to high for it to be correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
int count(int arr[]){

int sum;

    //Average
    for(int i=0;i<100; i++)
        sum = sum + arr[i];

    printf("Average:%f \n", sum/100);

}
int main()
{
    int array[100]; //RANDOM NUMBERS 0-900

count(array);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haha, `RANDOM NUMBERS`... Nope...

Comment: I just didnt post the random function xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize `sum` to zero before using it. C or C++ does not do this automatically for you in case of variables with automatic storage duration. It takes "time", and in C or C++ you don't pay for what you don't need. Otherwise you get a junk value (whatever its stored at that memory address, and technically it is undefined behaviour to use un-initialized variables except in assignments).

You also need to initialize the array, like

```
int arr[100]{}; // C++11 or later
```

or

```
int arr[100] = {0}; // C++98 or good old C
```

then fill it up with values. Do not consider the junk values as "random numbers", since again you are encountering undefined behaviour and the program is not altogether safe.

Comment: Ahh thank you! its always somethin easy i just forget

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behaviour(UB):

```
sum = sum + arr[i];
```

You have used `sum` above and it was not initialized. It is UB to read values of uninitialized variables in C and C++.

Actually given your code it is even once again UB because neither array values `arr[i]` are initialized.

Answer (score 2):

`sum` contains `garbage value`. Do initialize variable sum`enter code here`.
To verify you can print before updating `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
int count(int arr[]){

int sum = 0; // <==================== initialize to zero

    //Average
    for(int i=0;i<100; i++)
        sum = sum + arr[i];

    printf("Average:%f \n", sum/100);

}
int main()
{
    int array[100]; //RANDOM NUMBERS 0-900

count(array);

 return 0;
}
```

Without this initialization, the local variable `sum` can have any arbitrary initial value. And you will end up with arbitrarily large `sum`. Which will throw off the average.

The reason for this is that local variables are NOT initialized to zero automatically (unlike global variables).